# Dictionary Of Dictionaries in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am reading an SQL table from SQl SERVER using C# code.

My data looks like this:

```
ZOO   Animal    Mn Tu
NDS     BAT     2   0
GOR     BAT     3   1
VTZ     BAT     1   2
MAS     BAT     0   0
CST     BAT     0   0
NDS     CAT     4   0
GOR     CAT     4   0
VTZ     CAT     2   0
MAS     CAT     7   0
CST     CAT     1   0
NDS     DOG     3   0
GOR     DOG     2   0
VTZ     DOG     1   0
MAS     DOG     3   0
CST     DOG     0   1
NDS     EGG     7   0
GOR     EGG     2   0
VTZ     EGG     0   0
MAS     EGG     0   0
CST     EGG     4   0
```

I wrote an sql reader command and it goes

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM table";

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;
        using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {


            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var location = reader.GetString(0).Trim();
                var animal= reader.GetString(1).Trim();
                var Monday= reader.GetValue(1).ToString().Trim();
                var Tuesday= reader.GetValue(3).ToString().Trim();

             }
        }
```

I created a Dictionary as follows:

```
 private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>> zooDict;
 zooDict= new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>();
```

I would ideally like to have a structure like this:

```
{
NDS:
    {
     BAT:
        {Mn: 2,
         Tu: 2},
     CAT:
        {
        MN: 4,
        Tu: 0
        }
     DOG:
        {
        MN: 3,
        Tu: 0
        }

     EGG:
        {
        MN: 7,
        Tu: 0
        }


    }
    GOR:
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .

}
```

I am hoping to convert this dictionary to a json file but I am unable to add keys and values to the empty dictionary. I come from python background where i can use defaultdict to create dictionary of dictionaries without running to the key errors.

Any tips to create the dictionary will be hugely appreciated.

---

```
if (!ZooDict.ContainsKey(location))
{
    var catDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    catDict.Add("Mon", Monday);
    catDict.Add("Tue", Tuesday);
    var AnimalDict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
    AnimalDict.Add(animal, catDict);
    waitlistDict.Add(location, AnimalDict);
}
else
{
    if (!waitlistDict[location].ContainsKey(animal))
    {
        var catDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        catDict.Add("Mon", Monday);
        catDict.Add("Tue", Tuesday);
        var AnimalDict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
        AnimalDict.Add(animal, catDict);
        waitlistDict[location] = AnimalDict;
    }
    else
    {
        if (waitlistDict[location][animal].ContainsKey("Mon"))
        {
            waitlistDict[location][animal]["Mon"] = Monday;
        }
        else
        {
            waitlistDict[location][animal]["Mon"] = Monday;
        }
        if (waitlistDict[location][animal].ContainsKey("Tue"))
        {
            waitlistDict[location][animal]["Tue"] = Tuesday;
        }
        else
        {
            waitlistDict[location][animal]["Tue"] = Tuesday;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your approach is correct. But you need to create innermost dictionary instance. Use `zooDict.Add("key", new Dictionary ();` where `key` is **bat**, etc

Comment: I was unable to add the inner dictionaries but now I think I got it.

Comment: can you show me how you are adding inner dictionary? I may be able to help you or correct your approach of adding dictionary.

Comment: @PratikGaikwad http://pastebin.com/GTJQugsD

Comment: For the record it looks like you're creating what will later become a confusing data structure IMHO

Comment: @Morpheus - You should edit your question to add the code - not add it via a link to external sites.

Comment: @Morpheus it looks like you are on right track but you're doing too much processing. I will post my answer once I log into to computer

Comment: I don't think Dictionaries are what you  need to solve this.  Custom classes would be much simpler.  Is there a requirement to use dictionaries?

Comment: I suspect all JSON libraries would support direct conversion from class objects too so you really should consider making it a class instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can fill the dictionary directly in your loop

```
private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>> zooDict =
     new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>();

while (reader.Read())
{
       var location = reader.GetString(0).Trim();
       var animal= reader.GetString(1).Trim();
       var Monday= reader.GetValue(1).ToString().Trim();
       var Tuesday= reader.GetValue(3).ToString().Trim();

       if(!zooDict.ContainsKey(location))
            zooDict[location] = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();

       zooDict[location][animal] = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
       {
             { "MN", Monday },
             { "Tu", Tuesday }
       };
}
```

As a side note, you might want to consider creating classes to represent your objects, add them to a dictionary or list, and use Newtonsoft Json.net (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to serialize them instead of using dictionaries for everything. For example, you can create a class:

```
public class Animal
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Monday { get; set; }
     public int Tuesday { get; set; }
}

var zooDict = new Dictionary<string, List<Animal>>();

// then in your while loop you do this 
if(!zooDict.ContainsKey(location))
    zooDict[location] = new List<Animal>();
zooDict[location].Add(new Animal() { /* fill Monday and Tuesday properties */ });
```

Of course, you can take this one step further and create a class with properties `string Location` and `List<Animal> Animals`, and eliminate dictionaries altogether. It depends on your use case(s) I guess

Comment: Classes would be much easier.

Comment: @TheGeekYouNeed  I am not very familiar with C#. I hope classes will solve the problem. I sporadically have to deal with code written by others. hence the confusion.

Comment: Morpheus is right, classes will eliminate frustrations here

Comment: @KMoussa  There seems to be an issue with the code, the Dictionary only lists one key, value pair which is the last element. i.e  CST     EGG     4   0

Comment: @Morpheus are you looking at it in the debugger or looping and printing? If printing can u share the code you use to print?

Comment: @TheGeekYouNeed I tend to agree, the only downside of classes is that the sample Json Morpheus shared doesn't look like the default serialization of lists (no Json arrays) so might require some customization to serializing (assuming the exact format is required)

Comment: @KMoussa  http://pastebin.com/ZQaZXzmC  The Console.WriteLine writes all the locations and animals etc

Comment: @Morpheus u need to move `waitlistDict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>();` outside the loop. Having it inside the loop creates a brand new dictionary in each iteration so u end up with only the last element

Comment: @KMoussa Sorry. I feel stupid. It's been a long day. Thanks A loT

Answer (score 8):

```
public class DataLine
{
    public string Zoo { get; set; }
    public string Animal { get; set; }
    public int Mn { get; set; }
    public int Tu { get; set; }
}
```

```
public IEnumerable<DataLine> ReadAllLines()
{
    ...
    using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            yield return new DataLine() { Zoo = reader.GetString(0).Trim(), Animal = reader.GetString(1).Trim(), Mn = reader.GetInt32(2), Tu = reader.GetInt32(3) };
        }
    }
}
```

```
var dictionary = ReadAllLines()
    .GroupBy(line => line.Zoo)
    .ToDictionary(zoo => zoo.Key,
                  zoo => zoo.ToDictionary(animal => animal.Animal,
                                          animal => new { animal.Mn, animal.Tu }));

var sb = new StringBuilder();

using (var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb))
{
    new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer().Serialize(sw, dictionary);
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: I prefer this answer much over mine, and I don't think any custom logic will be needed for serialization either, upvote